# Database driven select box being empty on submit

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I am trying to submit a form value in a database with php. In form a select box value comes from database.

```
<?php include_once 'header.php';
$sql="SELECT uid,name FROM emitra_basic where block='$user'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//form validion
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
  $eid =$_POST["eid"];
  if($eid=="blank")
 {
     $flag=1;
  $idErr="please Select E-MITRA";
 }
$miatm =trim($_POST["miatm"]);
 if(empty($miatm) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/",$miatm)) {
$flag=1;
 $miErr="Please Enter Valid Id";
 }
 .............like this
if($flag==0)
{
$sqll="insert into **********";
  }
```

//my form is

```
<form id="basic" method="post" name="basic"> 
<select class="select-style gender" name="eid">
        <option value="blank">Please Select E-MITRA ID</option>
        <?php
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['uid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['uid']." (" . $row['name'] .")"; ?></option>
<?php
 }
?>
</select>

    <p class="contact"><label for="bid">Micro-ATM Serial No</label></p> 
<input type="text" name="miatm" value ="<?php if (isset($miatm)) echo $miatm; ?>"    /> <?php echo $miErr; ?>

 <p class="contact"><label for="bid">Micro-ATM TID No</label></p> 
<input type="text" name="tid" value ="<?php if (isset($tid)) echo $tid; ?>" /> <?php echo $tiErr; ?>

   <input class="buttom" name="submit" id="submit"  value="Add Me" type="submit">
```

Its seems Ok.but when i tried to submit the form if some of one field remain empty then its show blank value in select box.
how can i remain the  same selected value in select box even if textbox remain empty.

Comment: first two line inside the php or not???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retain the value of drop down after form submit.

User [selected](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option) attribute of `select option`.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $eid =$_POST["eid"];
  if ($eid=="blank") {
    $flag=1;
    $idErr="please Select E-MITRA";
  }
}
$sql="SELECT uid,name FROM emitra_basic where block='$user'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<select class="select-style gender" name="eid">
<option value="blank">Please Select E-MITRA ID</option>
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $selected = (isset($_POST["eid"]) && $_POST["eid"] == $row['uid']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['uid']; ?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $row['uid']." (" . $row['name'] .")"; ?></option>
<?php
 }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `selected=""` or `selected="selected"` after submission in your select tag as a attribute as:

```
<?
$sql="SELECT uid,name FROM emitra_basic where block='$user'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<select class="select-style gender" name="eid">
    <option value="blank">Please Select E-MITRA ID</option>
    <?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $selected = ((isset($_POST["eid"]) && $_POST["eid"] == $row['uid']) ? 'selected=""' : '');
    ?>
    <option <?=$selected?> value="<?php echo $row['uid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['uid']." (" . $row['name'] .")"; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $eid = $_POST["eid"];
        if($eid=="blank")
        {
           $flag=1;
           $idErr="please Select E-MITRA";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

**Side Note:**

In your question ist two lines are not inside the php, i hope this is type error.

Comment: values comes in select box but it gots empty if i try to submit with one text box empty

Comment: @omnath: i suppose you are using </form> ending tag in your code ?? is it? didnt see in your code